# UIButton in TableViewCell not responding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button"])
{
    UIView *ButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 25)];
    UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    Button.frame = CGRectMake(90, 5, 90, 30);
    [Button setTitle:@"PopOver" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ButtonView addSubview:Button];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ButtonView];
    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(showPickerPopupAction)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    Button.tag = indexPath.row; 
}
```

- (void) showPickerPopupAction
{
    NSLog( @"Button clicked." );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Button's frame is almost completely outside the ButtonView's frame.  If you set a backgroundColor on the ButtonView, you'll see that only the top-left corner of the button is in the ButtonView frame and only that corner will respond to touches.

Adjust the size of the ButtonView frame or the size and position of the Button frame so that the button is completely inside ButtonView.

Not sure why you need ButtonView in the first place.  You could just add Button directly to the contentView.

Also, you should do `[ButtonView release]` after adding ButtonView to the cell.contentView.

Comment: ButtonView is just an empty view. My app has TableView Controller, and I am trying to populate all controls in individual table row /cell. I am stuck at PickerView Controller, PopOverController, Button. Works fine this way with slider, textboxfield etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"] autorelease];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

UIButton *buttonLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [buttonLeft setTitle:@"Left" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [buttonLeft setFrame: CGRectMake( 10.0f, 3.0f, 145.0f, 40.0f)];
 [buttonLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavorites) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIButton *buttonRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[buttonRight setTitle:@"Right" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonRight setFrame: CGRectMake( 165.0f, 3.0f, 145.0f, 40.0f)];
[buttonRight addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavorites) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:buttonLeft];
[cell addSubview:buttonRight];

[backgroundView release];

-(void) addToFavorites {}

Works fine !!
```